# i had an jquery page , i want to add it to the android activity,how it could be done?

Tags: android-webview

I am new to android developement.i had created one page in jquery using html and css and i want to add it to the android activity but i am unable to do it,can anyone please provide me proper code for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to make a hybrid app (using HTML/CSS/Javascript to make an application but still have native Android functionality) I would take a look into [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). Just follow the directions and it lets you upload HTML/CSS and your AndroidActivity simply has to open it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion but sir i had already tried for the phonegap and i found that it only convert the html/css/jquery to the android apk file but i want to add sinlge page in my android application? please solve my query?

Comment: Hmmm I guess I'm still a little confused about what you're trying to do. If you don't mind me asking, what exactly are you trying to do with this application? Does the android application do something but you also want to show a single webpage? I feel either way, the android application is going to somehow need to access your browser to open an HTML file so the Phonegap way is the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for answers,meanwhile i found the way to do it,i am done it using Phonegap as u said earlier but in diffferent way.

Comment: for anyone who also face such problem.please refer to the link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html;it will surely helps..

Comment: I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer. I wasn't wrong to suggest Phonegap. The whole point of Phonegap is to provide native Android functionality to your web applications so you can make use of their APIs to access the Accelerometer, Camera, etc. I'm glad you found your answer though.